# Cerrar ventana cmd después de ejecutar script para apagar pantalla con powershell

Tags: cmd, powershell

He creado un acceso directo a cmd para que me ejecute un script de powershell el cual solo apaga la pantalla, el motivo de esto es que cmd permite anclar accesos directos en la barra de tareas.

Pero necesito que al ejecutar el script, después de llevarlo a cabo, la ventana se cierre automáticamente, que es lo que no he conseguido.

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)
```

Comment: exit no funciona?

Comment: @Dr.Manhattan no, cierra la ventana sin ejecutar el script

Comment: Prueba a agregar start en la primera linea de comandos y exit en la última.
También prueba a poner exit 0 en vez de exit a secas. Y nos cuentas La respuesta de Alejandro Teixeira Muñoz también me convence

Comment: @dpfernandez10 conseguiste hacerlo?

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz no, probé otra vez a crear un shortcut con el script que publiqué y hay veces que al iniciar esta la ventana abierta y otras que no, no se la razón, quizás el tiempo que lo dejes abierto, si queréis probarlo, es útil en mi caso para ausentarme y dejar cosas en 2º plano y al volver pida pass.

Comment: En mi caso, siempre se cierra la ventana. Has añadido el Exit??? Me refiero... ya sabemos que tu script no funciona, y se supone que tú debes comprobar si NUESTRA SUGERENCIA funciona. ¿Has probado a añadirlo?

Comment: `&& exit` perdon.

Answer (score 1):

> Un signo ampersand (&) vale para ejecutar varios comandos en una
>   linea.  Dos signos ampersand (&&) valen para ejecutar varios comandos
>   en una linea, pero el segundo sólo se ejecuta si el primero finaliza
>   OK.

Prueba a añadir `&& exit`

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2) && exit
```

> La [documentación de microsoft](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) de powershell
>
> La de [DOS](https://gerardnico.com/lang/dos/control_operator) (punto 3.3)